# I can't get acccess to Tuya cloud API

Tags: postman, tuya

I have been struggling with connecting to Tuya cloud API. Testing in postman gives me this result:

[image]

The things I have done:

1. I connected the device to Tuya developer account.
2. I configured my developer account and have access to tuya IOT service.
3. I set up testing environment as shown in this link: https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/set-up-postman-environment?id=Ka7o385w1svns
4. I made sure that I have turned off the cloud IP Allow list.

Yet still that error occurs although when I send a request through API Explorer on the tuya site everything works correctly. Can someone know the origin of this error?

Answer (score 0):

So I also stumbled upon this question and managed to get Tuya's cloud api working. Here is what I tried for future reference:

1. Make sure device is setup in the [right region](https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/oem-app-data-center-distributed?id=Kafi0ku9l07qb)
2. Enabled the specific API you are using in Tuya Cloud Services page
3. Check if your request is being blocked by using a VPN/Web server